# Create a list of RadioElement via the values of a list in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, monotouch.dialog, radioelement

I want to create a list of `RadioElement` via the values of an ArrayList.
Imagine I have a list:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<MyClass> mylist
```

Now I don't want to iterate through all elements and create a `RadioElement` for everyone. Is it possible to create the `RadioElements` automatically by a property of `MyClass`, by passing the `List<MyClass>`.
And how can I get the `Tapped` Event when the user selects one of the `RadioElements`?

Answer (score 0):

Linq to the rescue: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397900.aspx

As an example, I created a MyClass with a bool property `CreateRadioElement` and an `ElementText` string property:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool CreateRadioElement { get; set; }

    public string ElementText { get; set; } 
}
```

Then I created a List of MyClass objects:

```
List<MyClass> elements = new List<MyClass>();
elements.Add(new MyClass { CreateRadioElement = true, ElementText = "1" });
elements.Add(new MyClass { CreateRadioElement = false, ElementText = "2" });
elements.Add(new MyClass { CreateRadioElement = true, ElementText = "3" });
elements.Add(new MyClass { CreateRadioElement = false, ElementText = "4" });
elements.Add(new MyClass { CreateRadioElement = true, ElementText = "5" });
```

So now we only want the MyClass objects with `CreateRadioElement` set to true:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> radioelementsQuery = from element in elements
                                          where element.CreateRadioElement == true
                                          select element;
```

Now you execute the query with a foreach loop:

```
foreach (MyClass mc in radioelementsQuery)
{
      Console.WriteLine("Element: {0}", mc.ElementText);
}
```

And you will only see 1, 3, and 5 in the console output. And of course instead of writing to the console, you could assign each to RadioElement.

Comment: I know how to create a list with values, filter it etc. My question is about the last part of your answer. You say I have to iterate through all the values and create a radioElement for each one? Isn't there a way to bound the list<MyClass> as source, so that Xamarin creates the radioElements automatically?

Comment: As far as I know Monotouch.Dialog does not have a binding mechanism. Note that Monotouch.Dialog is not actively supported by Xamarin any longer, though it is open source. You might want to use Xamarin.Forms instead which has a built in binding mechanism.